# Add param to all objects in an Array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Objects like:

```
[
   {
      title: 'Title 1',
      value: 'value 1'
   },
   {
      title: 'Title 2',
      value: 'value 2'
   }
]
```

I need to add a new param to all the objects.

I know I can do a for over the array and modify each object, I'm trying to find a way to solve with a native method. Does that exists?

Comment: There are any number of ways to hide the fact that you're looping (`forEach`, `map` etc), but in the end what you need is a simple loop.

Comment: yeah, it just look nice I guess

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arrayObj=[
   {
      title: 'Title 1',
      value: 'value 1'
   },
   {
      title: 'Title 2',
      value: 'value 2'
   }
];

arrayObj.forEach(function(obj){
  obj.newProp='new';
  });
console.log(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
a.forEach(function(item,index){
item.newParam=index

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdwvsmu2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

`YourList.forEach(function(entry) { 
    entry['newElement'] = "test";
    console.log(entry);
});`